# Find the largest multiple of 3 from array of digits in O(n) time complexity

Tags: c

Given an array of digits (0 to 9). Find the largest number that can be made from some or all digits of array and is divisible by 3. The same element may appear multiple times in the array, but each element in the array may only be used once.
Examples:
Input : arr[] = {5, 4, 3, 1, 1}
Output : 4311

Algorithm

1. Get array size and array input and calculate sum while getting input.
2. Sort the array in ascending order
3. Take three queues, Iterate array and divide digit by 3 and put in respective queues based on remainder,
   Queue0 to hold digit % 3 == 0
   Queue1 to hold digit % 3 == 1
   Queue2 to hold digit % 3 == 2
4. Calculate remainder = sum % 3, 
   if remainder is equal to 1, Dequeue one element from Queue1 or two dequeue from Queue2
   else if remainder is equal to 2 Dequeue one element from Queue2 or two dequeue from Queue1
5. Merge Queue0, Queue1 and Queue2 into one queue
6. Sort merge queue in descending order
7. Print merged queue.

Code

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main()
{
    int n,sum=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n],q1[n],q2[n],q3[n];
    int c1=0,c2=0,c3=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    sum+=a[i]; }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(a[i]%3==0) {
            q1[c1]=a[i]; c1++; }
        else if(a[i]%3==1) {
            q2[c2]=a[i]; c2++; }
        else {
            q3[c3]=a[i]; c3++; }
    }
    if(sum%3==1&&c1!=0)
    c1--;
    else {
        if(c2>1)
            c2-2;
        else
            printf("Not Possible");
    }
    if(sum%3==2&&c2!=0)
    c2--;
    else {
        if(q1>1)
            c1-2;
        else
            printf("Not Possible");
    }
    int k=0,b[n];
    for(int i=0;i<c1;i++) {
        b[k]=q1[i]; k++; }
    for(int i=0;i<c2;i++) {
        b[k]=q2[i]; k++; }
    for(int i=0;i<c3;i++) {
        b[k]=q3[i]; k++; }
    }
```

I am new to coding and couldn't figure out sorting and merging queue in O(n). Need help with step 2 and 5.

Comment: Since the array contains only single digit numbers, you don't need the three queues. What you need is a histogram of the digits.

Comment: Don't we need 2 loops for a histogram. Code needs to be in O(n)                                                                         
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)                                                                                                 
    for(j = 0; j < inputValue; j++)                                                                                     
        if ( hist[j] == i)                                                                                                        
           results[i]++;

Comment: @ Arjun You can do it with one loop. `int h[10]={0}; for (i=0; i<n; i++) h[a[i]]++;` In fact, you can compute the histogram while reading the input. You don't even need the `a` array. Read each digit, update the sum, and update the histogram.

Comment: In step 4, you'll reduce the count of one or two digits in the histogram. Then to generate the output it does take two loops: `for (i=9; i>=0;i--) for (count=h[i]; count>0; count--) result[r++] = i;` But those two loops execute a total of `n` times, since the counts in the histogram sum to `n`.

Comment: If like to propose what I think is a faster approach in general. Not just no queues, but a simple condition to determine the divisibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort in `O(n)`, you'll want to use [Radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

```
// Let's start with the array that your code generates in step 5
int b[4] = {1, 1, 4, 3}

// Count the number of times each value is seen.
int buckets[10] = {};
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
  buckets[b[i]]++;

// Update the b array with the sorted data.
int *b_iterator = &b[0];
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
  for (int count=0; count<buckets[i]; count++)
    *b_iterator++ = i;

// b is now sorted. {1, 1, 3, 4}.
```

Comment: There's no need to do the unpacking for what OP is looking for. The histogram contains all necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

1.Sort the array in increasing order(Counting Sort).
2.Queue q0 stores the elements which on dividing by 3 gives remainder 0.
3.Queue q1 stores the elements which on dividing by 3 gives remainder 1.
4.Queue q2 stores the elements which on dividing by 3 gives remainder 2.
5.Find the sum of all the given digits.Let it be ‘s’.
6.If s is divisible by 3,goto step 9.
7.If s when divided by 3 gives remainder 1:
Remove one item from q1.
If q1 is empty,remove two items from q2.
If q2 contains less than two elements,number is not possible.
8.If s when divided by 3 gives remainder 2:
Remove one item from q2.
If q2 is empty,remove two items from q1.
If q1 contains less than two elements,number is not possible.
9.Empty all queues into an temporary array and sort it in decreasing order.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main()
{
    int n,max,f=0,c=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n],ct[10]={0},b[10],sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        sum+=a[i];}
    max=a[0];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(max<a[i])
            max=a[i];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        ct[a[i]]+=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=max;i++)
        ct[i]+=ct[i-1];
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
        b[--ct[a[i]]]=a[i];
    if(sum%3==0)
        goto print;
    else if(sum%3==1) {
        for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
            if(b[i]%3==1) {
                b[i]=-1; f=1;
                goto print;
            }
    }
    else {
        for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
            if(b[i]%3==2) {
                b[i]=-1; f=1;
                goto print;
            }
    }
    if(f==0&&sum%3==1) {
        for(int i=n-1;i>=0&&c<2;i--)
            if(b[i]%3==2) {
                b[i]=-1;
                c++;
            }
    }
    if(f==0&&sum%3==2) {
        for(int i=n-1;i>=0&&c<2;i--)
            if(b[i]%3==1) {
                b[i]=-1;
                c++;
            }
    }
    print:
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
        if(b[i]!=-1)
            printf("%d",b[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to enhance your answer by explaining **what** you are doing? Code alone is not a good answer.

Comment: I hope the edit is sufficient enough to explain the code. @thebusybee

Comment: Please show how your description maps to the source. For example, I can't find the emptying of the queues and sorting in step 9, if it is jumped to in step 6. -- Additionally, your source is very, very dense and hard to follow. Please look up some code styles, choose one, and stick to it. The names of your variables should be more descriptive. (I wrote such code when I started with C many years ago; in the meantime I learned the hard way that it is an error.)

Comment: sorry for that my mistake i modified the original code a lot. i just put all sorted elements in array b and  and check the remainder of sum of all elements if it is 1 i use a for loop to traverse array b and check if b[i]%3==1 and replace it with -1 if no elements are available to replace i replace 2 b[i]%3==2 elements using flag f.The same goes for sum%3==2. if sum%3==0 i just print the array in reverse. for others i print all elements other than -1 in reverse to get the largest multiple of 3 from array of digits. @thebusybee

Comment: I am new to coding. Its only been a month since i joined college. I  never had programming before. Now i am not just learning to code in c but also coding Data Structures in c.